# Replace all Tabs within all txt files

Tags: vba, replace

I have a folder with multiple text files and I need to replace all of the tabs within each file with a Space.

What is the easiest way to do this with VBA?

Thanks in advance
Geoff

Comment: The easiest way to not do this in VBA is use this: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=findandreplace

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TabsToSpace()
    Dim f As String, pth As String

    pth = "your_directory_path\"

    f = Dir(pth & "*.txt")
    While f <> ""
        Documents.Open FileName:=pth & f

        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "^t"
            .Replacement.Text = " "
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With

        ActiveDocument.Save
        ActiveDocument.Close

        f = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get an object required error, do I need a reference or, do I need to incorporate this into some other code? Thanks